# Django Simple POST Class View Not Working

Tags: python, django

I am experimenting with Django class based views and for some reason this simple post view does not seem to be working. When looking at my terminal it gets stuck on the GET method / validation of the csrf token. It is either not being validated or not saving to the database and therefore not being redirected to the thank-you page. I am not sure how to solve this issue. It definitely is not being saved to the DB, but as far as I am aware everything is correct here. I also am using a class based form which is why I am simply just calling form.save() The code is as follows:

```
class ReviewView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = ReviewForm()

        return render(request, 'reviews/review.html', {
            'form': form
        })
        
    def post(self, request):
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thank-you')

        return render(request, 'reviews/review.html', {
            'form': form
        })
```

Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated!

Comment: does your form have a model and are you filling the form out correctly? and in html does your form have method="POST"?

Comment: Yes to both of those, that is why this seems like such a strange issue to me lol. For whatever reason the post function just is not being called after submission